# new window on click a info window possible on fusion table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

What I want to do, add a short data with [Read More] on info window. When user click over [Read More] full data will be shown. Can't find any documentation how to do that on fusion table/layer, is it possible using fusion?

For better understanding

Normal info window shows-

```
    {name}
    {address}

..[Read More]
```

If user clicks on [Read More]

```
{name}
{address}
{mobile}
{email}
{facebook}
{description}
```

Please share guideline/documentation if its possible on fusion table/layer.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

create a infowindow-template like this:

```
<div class='googft-info-window'>
 {name}<br>
 {address}<br>
 <span class="readmore">[...Read More]</span>
 <div class="more">
  {name}<br>
  {address}<br>
  {mobile}<br>
  {email}<br>
  {facebook}<br>
  {description}<br>
 </div>
</div>
```

The infowindow will now have 2 elements with a particular class:

1. ```
   <div class="more">
   ```

   This element contains the elements that initially should be hidden, hide it via CSS:

   ```
   .gm-style-iw .more{
     display:none;
   }
   ```
2. `<span class="readmore">[...Read More]</span>`

   You can't assign a event-handler to this element in the infoWindow-template, observe the click in the document instead:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'click', function(e){
     if(e.target.className==='readmore'){
       //do something
     }
   });
   ```

**How to apply the desired functionality:**

Observe the click on the layer:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'click',function(e,showMore){

    //when the event has been triggered by a real click on the layer
    //the  showMore-argument is undefined
    //store the event-data as properties of the  layer 
    //because we need this data to trigger the click programmatically
    if(!showMore){
      //the complete event-data
      this.eventData=e;
      //store  the unmodified infowWindowHtml separate, because we will modify it
      this.infoWindowHtml=e.infoWindowHtml;
    }
     //wrap the contents in  another div
     //when showMore is defined assign a particular class to the wrapper
     e.infoWindowHtml='<div'+
                      ((showMore)?' class="showmore" ':'')+'>'+
                      this.infoWindowHtml+
                      '</div>';

 });
```

Trigger a click on the layer in the handler mentioned above and pass 2 arguments:

1. the original event
2. `true`(this will be the `showMore`-variable)

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'click', function(e){
    if(e.target.className==='readmore'){
     google.maps.event.trigger(layer,'click',layer.eventData,true)
    }
   });
   ```

The infoWindow will immediately open again(there is no need to request the data again), but re-opening is required, because the API must re-calculate the size of the infoWindow.

Use CSS to:

....show the initially hidden content:

```
.gm-style-iw .showmore .more{
  display:block;
}
```

...hide the *read more*-span:

```
.gm-style-iw .showmore .readmore{
  display:none;
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pmrzytfL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pmrzytfL/)